# When do we find out who Miranda Keyes' Mother is?

Tags: video-games, halo

In the Halo universe, it is well know that Miranda is the daughter of Captain Jacob Keyes. In the recent Halo: Glasslands it is made obvious that her mother is:

> Dr Catherine Halsey

However, when was it mentioned before this, if at all?

Comment: nothing wrong with your question, but I am wondering if it would fit better at: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JustinC - nope, I don't think they'd like it. I've seen similar questions closed over there

Comment: @JustinC there's an understanding of sorts between arqade and scifi.se that we get the plot questions and they handle the mechanics questions. We consider video games a valid form of expression for science fiction/fantasy stories: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/319/can-i-ask-a-question-about-video-game-based-scifi-fantasy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The entries occur in [her mother's journal](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Dr._Halsey%27s_personal_journal), included with the Halo: Reach limited edition. Among other things, it documents her growing feelings for Jacob (Keyes), and the eventual birth and separation of Miranda and her mother.